# I can't click any button that is in Power BI

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

**Description:**

Good afternoon community, could you help me know how to click a button in a Power BI interface? I was trying this but it doesn't work for me

```
await page.ClickAsync(".themableBackgroundColor");
```

**Url Power Bi**:

```
https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNGE3Mjg4OWMtZTFhYi00MDUyLTllNzAtNDJmOGE4NjY2MzMwIiwidCI6IjhhNDc1YTdmLThlOGYtNDliMi1iMDRkLTZlY2IwNTkzYzYzMyJ9
```

**Image of Power Bi buttons**:

[Image of Power Bi buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lVrO.png)

**Example code Html**

```
<button type="button" class="themableBackgroundColor" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block; background-color: transparent; cursor: pointer;">
<span class="button-text" style="text-align: right; max-width: 32px; pointer-events: none; color: rgb(102, 102, 102); font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13.3333px; position: absolute; right: 4px; top: 20px;"></span>
<div class="button-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 22.59 32" width="32" height="32" style="fill: none; pointer-events: none; position: absolute; left: 4px; top: 4px;"><polygon points="20.04 29.25 11.21 25.43 2.37 29.25 2.37 2.5 20.04 2.5 20.04 29.25" style="vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke; stroke-width: 3px; stroke: rgb(102, 102, 102); stroke-opacity: 1;"></polygon></svg></div>
<div class="button-outline" style="pointer-events: none; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; width: 40px; height: 40px; border: none;"></div>
</button>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any errors. The problem is that I don't get the click event.
This button is integrated into a power bi web and when I click on the button it takes me to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function to click the button via script:

```
let btn = document.querySelector(".themableBackgroundColor")
btn.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("Button Clicked!"))
btn.click();
```

Comment: I added this command as I am working in c # and I don't see any effect
  
     `await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync(@"() => {
                    let btn = document.querySelector('.themableBackgroundColor')
                    btn.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Button Clicked!'))
                    btn.click();
                            }");`